# PhoneGap 2.9.0 is not working Build error

Tags: ios, objective-c, build, cordova

Hi i tried to download and run phoneGap-2.9.0  but it showing following error..please check the image for error
[image]

I saw several answers like

1. In your Target's Build Settings, find "Other Linker Flags"
2. Change "$(TARGET_BUILD_DIR)/libCordova.a"
3. To "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/libCordova.a"

i tried all these but its not working please refer my images

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened with me also, and then i get to its fault. The problem is with the project folder, the project folder is not created properly.

In my case, i have some path issue, for which the application can't able to find the cordova lib folder.
it needed to recreated the whole project, then it worked fine for me.

Try to recreate the application folder, you can have a look into [this](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#iOS%20Platform%20Guide) while creating the application.

Comment: check if you might get some solution over here. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/phonegap/IcR8-ijrUfk/G1BvG1KJpnIJ